# I need help with a logic exercise.

Tags: logic

I am having trouble solving this exercise.
I must use the rules of inference and equivalence to solve it.

[image]

I need to demonstrate:
**L → (J→M)**

Premise 1: **~J → K**

Premise 2: **(L ∧ L) →  M**

I already made a truth table and the result is a tautology. Which means that the problem is demonstrable using the laws of inference and equivalence.

[image]

I have researched on the internet and have seen some videos on the subject but the exercises they show are easy.

I know that I must use all the premises to get to the demonstration.

I know that I must use the laws to create other premises and I know that I have to use all the premises for the demonstration.

I need to demonstrate: **L → (J→M)**
So starting at the end I would get **(L ∧ J) →  M** using the export law.
This means that I must isolate **J** *from premise one* and **L** *from premise 2* to later join them by the law of conjunction.

I don't know for example if I can use the law indempotency in the premise two to get **L → M** or I can only do that if the **(L ∧ L)** is isolated.

I have worked hours in this exercise. I have my forms, but I can't find the answer.

I can not apply an MPP, MTT or MTP because I do not have isolated premises that help me to clear.

*To clarify. It is this type of exercise:*
[image]

**Can anybody help me please.**
Thank you for taking the time to read the question.

Comment: Do I need to ask in other way to get help instead negative points?

Comment: Read your book or at least show some self work around the problem.

Comment: @JorgeArturoQuiroz I have edited the question. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

The lay out of the the question is odd, but I assume  $(L \land L) \to M$ is the second premiss.

Hint 1. The first premiss is irrelevant to the conclusion.

Hint 2. To prove the conclusion, assume the antecedent $L$ and aim for the consequent.

Hint 3. Do you know how to argue from a wff $\gamma$ to the conditional $\alpha \to \gamma$, whatever $\alpha$ is?

Comment: I have edited the question. I think the first premiss is relevant to get the J needed in the demostration.

Comment: No. The question is trying to trick you into thinking that, but the first premiss is not needed. Assume $L$. It follows that $L \land L$. Hence $M$. Hence $\alpha \to M$ for any $\alpha$ you choose, including $J$, $K$ or whatever you like. SO: you can get from $L$ to $J \to M$. Which establishes your conclusion. How exactly you implement this proof will then depend on the details of the proof system you are using.

Comment: At school they have not explained anything to me about Well-formed Formula (wff). I'm looking for information right now. I speak Spanish.